# Add animation to scrolltop menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

so i was messing around with getting menu to animate in after a certain div. I got it to work to show up but not to actually animate. I have already tried some different things with like .animate or fadein but it didnt work. Not sure what im doing wrong but mind you i am a jquery noob.

So my question is how can i easily animate this?

my code:

```
/* Menu show */
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var menuBG = $('.menu'),
        targetScroll = $('#slide2').position().top,
        currentScroll = $('html').scrollTop() || $('body').scrollTop();
    menuBG.toggleClass('show-menu', currentScroll >= targetScroll);
});
```

Comment: please place your html and css
maybe your div or menu has wrong "Position" css values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to achieve this. I'll demonstrate two one based on `jQuery` with some changes to the original code and another on `CSS3` with no changes to the original code but some additions in css.

**example 1 - jquery**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XL6VB/)

**html**

```
<div class="menu">this is the red menu</div>
<div id="slide2">this the blue slide2</div>
```

**css**

```
.menu{
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
}

/*.menu.show-menu{
    display:block;
}*/

#slide2{
height:800px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

**js**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var menuBG = $('.menu'),
        targetScroll = $('#slide2').position().top,
        currentScroll = $('html').scrollTop() || $('body').scrollTop();
    //menuBG.toggleClass('show-menu', currentScroll >= targetScroll);
    if(currentScroll>=targetScroll){
        $('.menu').fadeIn(1000);
        $('.menu').addClass('show-menu');
    }else{
        $('.menu').stop();
        $('.menu').removeClass('show-menu');
        $('.menu').fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

**example 2 - css3**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2A94/)

**css**

```
.menu{
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    /* display:none; */
    opacity:0;
    position:fixed;
}

.menu.show-menu{
    /* display:block; */
    opacity:1;
}

#slide2{
height:800px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: @johnzy87db if the answer has met your requirements please mark as accepted in order to assist other users as well, thanks